# How to include a JS script to a part of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noob needs help!
Is it possible to include a script within a part of the page? The trouble is theat one part of the form needs JQuery chained and the other needs regular JQuery. Here's the code:

```
$result=$result."
        Выберите тематику: <select id='thematic' name='thmsel'>
            <option></option>
            <option value='fb'>Стадион</option>
            <option value='sch'>Школа</option>  
            <option value='sw'>Бассейн</option>                              
        </select>
        Выберите раздел: <select id='catch' name='catsel'>
            <option></option>
            <option value='news' class='fb'>Новости</option>
            <option value='articles' class='fb'>Статьи</option>
            <option value='news' class='sch'>Новости</option>
            <option value='articles' class='sch'>Статьи</option>    
            <option value='news' class='sw'>Новости</option>
            <option value='articles' class='sw'>Статьи</option>
        </select>
        Выберите категорию: <select id='chap'name='chsel'>
            <option></option>
            <option value='world' class='news'>Мировые новости</option>
            <option value='rf' class='news'>Новости РФ</option>
            <option value='vlg' class='news'>Новости города</option>
            <option value='our' class='news'>Наши новости</option>
            <option value='useful' class='articles'>Полезное</option>
            <option value='humour' class='articles'>Юмор</option>   
        </select>
        <br>
        <script src='jquery.chained.min.js'></script>
        <script charset='utf-8'>
        $(function(){
            $('#catch').chained('#thematic');
            $('#chap').chained('#catch');
        });
        </script>

        ";


        $result=$result."
        <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        Заголовок новости: &nbsp <input type='text' name='title' value='' size='158'>
        <input type='hidden' name='state' value='save' />
        <textarea id='editor1' name='txt'></textarea></br>
        <submit type='button' value='Save'></form>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
                var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                AjexFileManager.init({
                    returnTo: 'ckeditor',
                    editor: ckeditor1
                });
            </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'> 
            function save()
            {
                for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
                        CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].updateElement();
                var data = $('#tdescription').val()

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php',
                data: data,

                success: function(html) {
                alert('Сохранено');
                }
            });

            }
            </script>";
```

I know that what I've done is wrong anyway because I'm trying to connect 3 different types of JQuery. SO that's why I'm here - to find out the proper way to to it correct. Thank you

P.S.> I've looked through the search, but haven't found anything that suits my needs.

Comment: I think you're using the word `jQuery` incorrectly

Comment: DJDavid98, what is incorrect? I'd better use it coorectly but I have to know what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) if you are going to use multiple versions together.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page).